# How to take photos quickly through iPhone using Ricoh Theta SC?

Tags: iphone, ricoh

I recently got a [Ricoh Theta SC](https://www.ricoh-imaging.nl/nl/theta-360/RICOH-THETA-SC.html). If I use it standalone I can press the shutter button, it will make a noise to indicate it is taking a picture. Within about 1 second I can take another picture by pressing the shutter button again.

Then I connect the camera to my iPhone using WiFi and the Theta software. Now when I take a picture I get a message "Processing Image" after each picture that takes 10-20 seconds even though as far as I can tell nothing is being transferred to the phone. I still have to manually switch to the list of taken pictures and download them to the phone if I want the picture that was just taken.

How I can prevent this "Processing Image" message and take pictures from the iPhone interface as fast as I can with the shutter button on the camera. The delay when using the phone makes it very uncomfortable to use with groups when I have to tell everyone "one more picture, wait, wait, wait, hold on the camera is still busy, wait, wait, just a moment, ..." whereas no such problem exists with the manual shutter button. Of course the problem with using the manual shutter button is my arm is then huge in the scene holding the camera .

Is there a setting that will avoid the image processing delay that only seems to happen when connected to the phone?

Comment: This is every bit as much on topic as asking why a flash does not behave as expected when using it via a wireless protocol. Someone is attempting to take a photo that they are in without having to hold the camera. That, it seems to me, is a photographic problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can be of small help, but I don't have an iPhone. On my Android app the camera will transfer the image to the phone, when you connect via Wifi and digitally trigger a shutter release.

I don't know, if that can be prevented, but: if your main problem is your thumb, switch on the theta while holding the wifi-button. This will set the camera to a 5s self-timer mode: push the shutter button, the (now green) LED will start flashing and take a picture after 5s. No thumb in the way!

Maybe intervall shooting could be an option, when you set that to the lowest interval time possible, but I guess that takes longer to set up.

Self timer mode might take 5s per picture, but you don't have to setup the Wifi-connection, so that might already be enough time gain. I bet you can take 10 pictures with that, before you even connected the app otherwise.